# Finding a Value in a Column

Tags: google-apps-script

I have the following which works great for finding a header value:

```
var lastCN = formResponsesSht.getLastColumn();
var data = formResponsesSht.getRange(1,1,1,lastCN).getValues();//Get 2D array of all values in row one
var data = data[0];//Get the first and only inner array
var statusCN = data.indexOf('Status') + 1;
```

Now I would like to find a value on a specific column. In this case B.

```
var lastRN = formResponsesSht.getLastRow();
var data = formResponsesSht.getRange(1,2,lastRN,1).getValues();//Get 2D array of all values in row one
var data = data[0];//Get the first and only inner array
var statusCN = data.indexOf('Status') + 1;
```

Why does this not work and is it possible to use the same strategy of `indexOf`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your sheet looked like this:

[image: screenshot]

Then the output of

```
var data = formResponsesSht.getRange(1,2,lastRN,1).getValues();
```

is: `[[a], [b], [c], [d], [e], [f], [g], [h], [i]]`

And

```
var data = data[0];
```

gets you: `[a]`, i.e. the first cell in that column.

`.getValues()` fetches data as an array where the "first and inner array" is an array of all the values in that row.

---

**Edit**: For finding the index of 'Status' in a column of data, try:

```
  for (var d = 0; d < data.length; d++) {
    if (data[d].indexOf('Status') > -1) {
      var statusCN = d + 1;  
      break;
    }
  }
  Logger.log(statusCN);
```

Comment: so because the data was in a row before it worked because all of the values were in one array, correct? Like this?: [[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i],[]]

Comment: Is there a proper way of doing this?

Comment: Sorry, I missed answering that in the first go. :-) Have added the snippet now. Hope this helps.

Comment: Got it. A for loop. Thanks for the quick response. I may be searching for more than one value but I think I can figure that one out on my own.

Comment: You may also want to try using [textFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder). Might be more efficient.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I think the max number of rows at any given time is 20 so efficiency is not a huge concern.